# Excel column graph with significantly different scales on data

Tags: excel, graph, charts, scale

I want to make a column chart for the following example:

```
            | 2018      | 2019      | 2020      | 2021      | 2022
--------|------------|------------|------------|------------|-----------
Series1 | 10,000,000 | 20,000,000 | 30,000,000 | 30,000,000 | 60,000,000
Series2 | 10,000     | 20,000     | 30,000     | 30,000     | 60,000
Series3 | 10         | 20         | 30         | 30         | 60
```

As you can see the issue here is to visualize those three columns next to each other while the data are in way different scales. I've tried playing with secondary-primary axis and formatting series with no success. While I might get the first two series the third one is almost invisible due to the very low scale.

Can you please elaborate me on how to do this?

Comment: If it is not important to keep the ratio of the 3 series to each other, than multiply the Series 3 values with 1000

Comment: Logarithmic scale also an approach

Comment: Assuming a line chart is used, even if the 3rd series is set to use the secondary vertical axis, but the 1st series data is 1000x larger than the 2nd series, the 2nd series will appear as almost a straight line overlapping the X-axis. No data trends will be visible since the scale difference is so large. Using a `logarithmic scale` is recommended in this case so all series are plotted meaningfully.